# how to text align right q-input in quasar framework ver 2

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I want to move the input label to the right in Quasar Framework Version 2. How can I do this? In my opinion, Quasar is very tricky and it's locked.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add css on your input like this

```js
<q-input v-model="text" label="Standard" input-style="text-align: right"></q-input>
```

the doc https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input